# How to use BBC's Imager.Js for responsive images in C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, css, image

I want to use BBC Imager.Js library to load responsive images on my website based on device window size. I have images of different sizes already stored on the server.

I have followed the documentation of BBC-News/Imager.js/ on github, but I could not get it to work due to lack of knowledge. Kindly help me how to accomplish this task or is there any better technique to do this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue. I was going to use this which is an old technique, for now a days use `<Picture>` tags for auto image selection based on the browser size from our image directory.

`<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="www.example.com/image-large.jpg, www.example.com/image-large.jpg 2x">
  <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="www.example.com/image-medium.jpg, www.example.com/image-medium.jpg 2x">
<source media="(min-width: 480px)" srcset="www.example.com/image-mobile.jpg, www.example.com/image-mobile.jpg 2x">
<source srcset="www.example.com/image-small.jpg, www.example.com/image-small.jpg 2x">
<img src="www.example.com/image-mobile.jpg" alt="@item.Title">
</picture>`

The Image tag in this picture tag is for older browser support hope it will be helpful.